# jQuery ajax() DELETE method?

Tags: jquery

Can I delete an item from a json file by passing the id of the item I want to delete? I'm getting:

> jquery-2.2.4.min.js: DELETE http://example.com/comments.json1 405
>   (Method Not Allowed)

Here's what I have:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  method: 'DELETE',
  url: comments.json1
});

// comments.json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "body": "abc",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "body": "xyz",
  }
]
```

Comment: is your web server capable of accepting delete requests?

Comment: How can I find that out?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70561/how-to-identify-the-http-methods-supported-by-a-web-server

Answer (score 0):

The DELETE-verb simply tells your API that a resource should be deleted. The verbs are used to differentiate methods that share the same endpoint.

Example:

Update a resource: 
    resource/id

Delete a resource:
    resource/id

Since the endpoints above are both the same we need som way to know which of these to endpoint the request was intended for. This is where we use the verbs.

Update a resource: 
    PUT/PATCH resource/id

Delete a resource:
    DELETE resource/id

This means a the keyword itself doesn't do anything, it simply explains which endpoint should be used.

405 means that the resource does not have a route corresponding to that verb.

[Further reading](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can take an easier approach. Just use `$_POST` or `$_GET`. And specially since you need to delete an item(*array element as per code provided*) from the json array. You should let the server-side script handle the validation and deleting.

The `PUT` and `DELETE` requests are not needed in a browser based web application environment(*Furthermore, modern browsers don't even support them, also their implementation has been removed from HTML5 specs too!!!*), and are more beneficial/useful for RESTful APIs.